# List all mailboxes a user has access to in Exchange 2013?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2013, exchange-management-shell

Is it possible to run a command to produce a list of mailboxes a user has full access to?

I found something to try running in PS AD module however the output was useless.

```
Get-ADUser mspencer -Properties * | Select msExchDelegateListBL | Export-Clixml 'c:\users\adm-dosmith\desktop\test23.csv'
```

Does anyone have anything?

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission -User mspencer
```

This goes through every mailbox and returns any permissions the user `mspencer` has.

You'll need to use the Exchange Management Shell to run it as it uses the Exchange cmdlets.

Answer (score 0):

To Filter only the Full Access Permissions for the specific user:

```
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission | 
? {$_.User -match 'mspencer' -and $_.AccessRights -contains "FullAccess"}
```